# Laravel trans not working with French special characters

Tags: php, laravel, translate

I have a Laravel site ,and translated it in multi language. It is all right for languages  as EN,DE,TR... but I'm having problems with french special chars .

English version:

```
<?php

return [
  'vip_2' => 'Stay logged in',
];
```

French version :

```
<?php
return [
  'vip_2' => 'Rester connecté',
];
```

This is how i call it on the view :

```
{{trans('vipFront.vip_2')}}
```

Where vipFront is the name of trans file . 
It wont return nothing if there is a character like 'é'or any other french special character .

Thank you .

Comment: Can you try `{{ Lang::get('vipFront.vip_2') }}` ?

Comment: Do you have the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag in your HTML? This only happens with the special characters? When you have a string without any special character in your french file, it works?

Comment: Yes is is working for ever character ,and also for some german special characters , all other french words are correct . , meta charset is utf-8

Comment: Is your translation file UTF-8 encoded? And what do you mean by *not working*? Any errors or example output?

Comment: If somone else have the same problem and you are working using sublime text editor , you have to save the file using File-> Save with encoding->UTF-8

Comment: I have the same error, all other langauges OK but french accents giving trouble. meta charset is utf-8. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I fixed only by editing the file and saving with utf-8 :/